# How to use ensemble of models in FM or FFM?

Tags: ensemble-modeling, kaggle

I am using Factorization Machines ( libfm) and also the Field Aware Factorization Machines (libffm) for a kaggle competition.  I am currently using the single models of each respectively for prediction. 
I came to know that we can use ensemble of models for both FM and FFM.
Can someone explain how  this is done ?

Comment: Most ensembling methods are independent from the internals of individual models, e.g. something like [majority voting](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ensemble_learning#Voting_based_methods), [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) or [model stacking](http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/) can be directly applicable to any model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ensembling methods are independent from the internals of individual models, e.g. something like [majority voting](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ensemble_learning#Voting_based_methods), [bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) or [model stacking](http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/) can be directly applicable to any model.

Note: this was originally a comment to the OP.